# What is the best practice for securing screw terminals on amps and distribution blocks?

Tags: electrical

So I installed a small underseat subwoofer (pictured below) in my car. Everything was good, but when I pushed the sub under my seat the power wire was strained due to a tight squeeze between the two rear mounting points for the seat. The sub just barely fits, and the additional pressure on the power wire popped it out of the screw terminal. Fortunately the fuse near the battery was out, or else I'd have gotten a nice shock, I'm certain!

I was rather surprised that the wire came loose because in my mind I had absolutely tightened that screw as tight as I felt comfortable without breaking something, but very little force was required to lever it out (pushing the sub under the seat from the rear floor was all I did and I didn't feel any major hangups). Is this just normal behavior with this mounting scheme, and is there something I can do better to retain the wires? I don't like the idea of a high amperage hot 12v source flopping around the cab of my vehicle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pushed the sub into position, you effectively had a large lever (the sub) against a small wire, terminal and screw.

The terminals are designed to be adequate for normal use, ie not loaded or having the wires under tension.

Making sure that the wires are not strained is good practice. One thing you could do is clip the wires to a retaining point so that the terminals are not under strain.